# Fixing broken links: diveintopython.org to diveintopython.net

Tags: support, broken-link

Links pointing to `diveintopython.org` are now broken, giving back `410 Gone` header.

For example: http://diveintopython.org/native_data_types/lists.html

It changed to `diveintopython.net`, for example:  http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html

[Link to search page on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22*diveintopython.org*%22&submit=search).

I'll edit now some, but don't have much time.. enjoy the hunt! :)